# CSS For <LI> Tag

Tags: css

I have a tab panel with three tabs.And below is the code that I got through the "FIREBUG" and noticed that only one of the tab that is rendered as `<LI>` has a class and rest of the two tabs does not have it.Is there any way that if I make some changes in Mozilla Firebug it gets reflected in the actual asp.net code forever.

```
<ul id="ext-gen59" class="x-tab-strip x-tab-strip-top">
<li id="tbGrid__pnlMain" class=" x-tab-strip-active">
<li id="tbGrid__pnlArticles" class="">
<li id="tbGrid__pnlCalendar" class="">
<li id="ext-gen60" class="x-tab-edge">
<div id="ext-gen61" class="x-clear"></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, changes in Firebug are client side. You need the actual source code and to update the files on the server for it to be live for everyone to see.

Comment: A `div` is ***not*** a valid child of a `ul`; fix your HTML and *then* see if things work more as you'd expect.

Answer (score 3):

Firebug cannot edit your code--it can only modify the page after it has been loaded.  It's a debugging tool.

Answer (score 2):

your code does not have closing of `li` tag...

you code may be

```
<ul id="ext-gen59" class="x-tab-strip x-tab-strip-top">
<li id="tbGrid__pnlMain" class=" x-tab-strip-active"></li>
<li id="tbGrid__pnlArticles" class=""></li>
<li id="tbGrid__pnlCalendar" class=""></li>
<li id="ext-gen60" class="x-tab-edge">
    <div id="ext-gen61" class="x-clear"></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps....